# Link remote light switches via nest

Tags: switch, wifi, iot

I have a light switch that controls the light on my front porch.   It was clearly designed for incandescent bulbs as CFLs always flicker when installed outside when the light is off as if a small current is running through.  This was apparently a common design with older timer switches if a "pilot light" style was not used.  The timer is shot as well, so I thought it might as well be time to replace the whole thing.

I have an additional switch across the house that is a one-way switch to turn on the light over the garage door.  I would like to be able to control both lights from both locations without having to redo any wiring.  Do any of the "Works with Nest" light switches on the market allow such a configuration whereby you could link the two switches together to remotely control each other?

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off topic.  Yes it can be done tho.  Don't marry yourself to "works with nest" tho--- in my opinion-- but opions are also off topic.

Comment: @Tyson I don't think a "does this exist?" question is the same as asking for product recommendations.

Comment: I don't have Nest, but I think you can create control groups with the app.  So you could add both switches to the group to be toggled simultaneously, rather than trying to wire them as a two-way switch.

Comment: There is a very thin line for half of the diy questions between "product recommendation" and "how do I do this". I'm looking for "how to do this" but obviously it requires a product of some sort.

Comment: @Chris I will look at that. Control groups were not a concept that I had seen mentioned yet when looking through literature, so thank you.